# Should we answer closed but answerable questions?

Tags: discussion

Say you're looking over the new questions, looking for a chance to solve someone's problem, and you see a question which is absolutely, unquestionably off-topic, or is much too localized, and it gets closed.

But you have the answer.

Should you share it anyway?

I do realize this is really a matter of personal choice, but I want to know what the community's general stance is.

Comment: a) Preferably not. b) How do you propose to do that? Closure prevents posting an answer. Via a comment?

Comment: I'd rather 1) write a new question based on whatever useful bits were there in the original one and 2) [self-answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/self-answer/info "what's this?") it. Then, I'd 3) post a comment in that "original" question, referring to a new one - to establish a link and let OP and other readers see my answer posted in a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post it as a comment, and the asker will be notified.

Comments are *generally* softer than answers, so I don't think you're going to get ratted on for it. At best, the user gets the answer they want, and you've helped somebody; at worst, the question gets deleted, taking the comment with it.

Comment: I know how, silly. I'm asking whether it's encouraged. Hence the "should".

Comment: I expanded my answer a little.